# ACRA: sometimes dialog report and other times silent report

Tags: android, acra

***What I want to do:***

> Get feedback on my Android app from within the app itself.

***What I've done:***

> I've just integrated the latest version of ACRA (4.4) to my Android
>   App.
>
> It has silent reports on crashes as the default behaviour

***What I want help with:***

> All I want to do is use the dialog report when I press a Feedback
>   button on my app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you want to achieve with your feedback button, but perhaps something like this?

For the configuration of the dialog look at https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#wiki-Dialog. The configuration could also be done in code in the `ACRAConfiguration` object if you do not want all this in your annotation.

You can then temporarily change the Reporting mode by using:

```
ACRAConfiguration config = ACRA.getConfig();
config.setMode(ReportingInteractionMode.DIALOG);
ACRA.setConfig(config);
doWhateverYourFeedbackButtonShouldDo();
config.setMode(ReportingInteractionMode.SILENT);
ACRA.setConfig(config);
```

where `doWhateverYourFeedbackButtonShouldDo()` can be something like:

```
ACRA.getErrorReporter().handleException(new UserFeedbackException(userFeedback));
```

Comment: Ok, the answer was incomplete but gave me the right direction, I'll edit it and accept.

Comment: waiting for it to be peer reviewed :(

Comment: Great to hear that I could help :)

Comment: So what is the complete answer then if this one is incomplete?

Comment: Since your edit was rejected I added some of your suggested edit into my original answer.

Comment: @deekay thanks that makes it complete. :) Don't know why it was rejected.

Comment: @william the answer is complete now