# Android - How to programmatically set USER_EMAIL in Acra crash report?

Tags: android, acra

My app uses ACRA to send a silent notification if the app crashes.

The [official documentation](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#set-an-email-address-to-be-added-to-reports) shows how to set the user email in XML and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382750/how-to-override-settings-of-acra-in-android) shows how to set it via annotations, but how can I set the user email address in code?

Presuming I've started off in the right direction, this is as far as I've got...

```
ACRA.init(this);
ACRAConfiguration acraConfig = ACRA.getConfig();
//acraConfig.howToSetUserEmail???
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to 323go's helpful answer, here is the working code:

```
import org.acra.*;
import org.acra.annotation.ReportsCrashes;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;

@ReportsCrashes(
    formKey = "", // This is required for backward compatibility but not used
    formUri = "http://example.com/crash-reports/my-script-which-emails-me-the-acra-data.php",
    sharedPreferencesName = "THE_NAME_OF_MY_SHARED_PREFS_FILE",
    sharedPreferencesMode = Context.MODE_PRIVATE
)
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // The following line triggers the initialization of ACRA
        ACRA.init(this);

    }

}
```

Then, elsewhere in my app, I set the `acra.user.email` preference in a similar manner as shown in the accepted answer, below.

Comment: Why the downvote / what's wrong with this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation says you can do it through `SharedPreferences`:

```
getSharedPreferences().edit().putString( "acra.user.email", "your@email.com" ).commit();
```

should do the trick. I haven't tested that, as I don't see much use for setting the email address at run-time in my setup.

Comment: That helped, thanks. I will update my question with the working code.